# hadaoop + Configuring NameNode Heap Size

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

in Short - we want to know how to configure the heap size for a name-node

so far we calculate the name-node heap size as the following

first we verified the number of files by - `hadoop fs -count / | awk '{print $2}'`

and once we get the number from `hadoop fs -count / | awk '{print $2}'`

then we verify what is the correct `name-node` heap size from the table - https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configuring-namenode-heap-size

but we don't sure if we need to consider also the HDFS replication factor ?

for example lets say we have `HDFS replica = 3`  and number of files is 5000000 ( from `hadoop fs -count / | awk '{print $2}'` )

so maybe we need to calculate the total number of files as `5000000 X 3 = 15000000`

and then take the number `15000000` and verified the name-node heap size according to `15000000` and not `5000000`

so am I correct about this?